# Extracting source code from a document for testing

Tags: ruby, documentation, markdown

I wrote tutorials for some Ruby gems I wrote. It is in markdown (Kramdown) text document. To ensure the integrity of the source code in the tutorials as the development of the gems continue I want to extract the source code from the tutorial document and run test to ensure the code is correct and working. Before reinventing the wheel I searched but found nothing on this kind of problem. Is there any software that can help me solve my problem? Ruby software would be cool but I'm not particular about the language. I'm sure I can't be the first person to encounter this problem.

The other option is to only have place holders in the tutorial documents and have all the files externally en then populate the document prior to publishing. This would mean a lot more loose files but would be significantly easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like [Ruby DocTest](https://github.com/tablatom/rubydoctest)?

Answer (score 0):

[Org mode](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Working-With-Source-Code) in emacs can do that, but it means you can't write in Markdown.